# Uses of Different Sitecore Topologies

Tags: installation, server-role

I am new in Sitecore and I have installed Sitecore 10.2 XP1 instance on my local machine.

I just want to know more about different roles in Sitecore topology and how they communicate with others.

1. Collection
2. Ma
3. Marketing Reporting
4. Prc
5. ProcessingEngine
6. RefData
7. Reporting
8. Search

Comment: If you are working on the LOCAL SYSTEM for DEVELOPMENT purpose then generally you can use XP0 topology which would be light as compared to XP1 topology.

For higher environment you can utilize XP1 or Scaled topology, and each role information present at https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/experience-platform-roles.html, e.g.  MA https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/marketing-automation-engine.html and its dependency and accessibility.

Answer (score 3):

To understand it very simply, Sitecore has produced a number of pre-built topologies which offer combinations of the split-out functionality:

**On-premise (IaaS) topologies**
Default on-premise (IaaS) topologies include:

- XP Single
- XP Scaled
- XM Scaled

**Azure (PaaS) topologies**
Azure (PaaS) includes the following default topologies

- XP Single
- XP Scaled
- XM Single
- XM Scaled

You can go through this article to know more about what configurations and roles come under each topology with their diagram.

- [Sitecore configurations and topology for Azure](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/sitecore-configurations-and-topology-for-azure.html)
- [The Anatomy of Sitecore](https://mintydog.com/2018/10/28/the-anatomy-of-sitecore-9-part-2-standard-topologies/)

You can download each release from the [Download Portal](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform.aspx)

As you mentioned in your question that you are using XP1 instance. So here are the details of each one that you want to know more about.

- **Collection**: The xConnect Collection service performs Receives contacts and interactions, either individually or in a batch, Allows reading of contact and interaction data by ID or identifier and Supports data extraction.
- **Ma**: The Marketing Automation Engine role processes campaign and activity enrollments, and moves contacts through campaigns
- **Marketing Reporting**: The Marketing Automation Reporting service allows you to retrieve plan and enrollment statistics using the Marketing Automation Reporting API
- **ProcessingEngine**: Processing Engine service performs data processing tasks at scale
- **RefData**: The Reference Data service allows you to create or retrieve reference data using the Reference Data Client API
- **Reporting**: The Marketing Automation Reporting service allows you to retrieve plan and enrollment statistics using the Marketing Automation Reporting API
- **Search**: The xConnect Collection Search service allows you to search contacts and interactions using the xConnect Client API or another API that consumes the oData service.

Here is the Sitecore documentation that you can refer to know about each role that is being used to configure a topology. It will give you all the information about the system roles or entities that can be scaled and configured in a wide variety of topologies

[Roles overview](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/roles-overview.html)

Finally, this diagram will help you to understand how they communicate with each other.

https://sitecorehacker.files.wordpress.com/2018/01/xp1-topology.png

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, The entire Sitecore product suite contains over 50 logical system roles or entities that can be scaled and configured in a wide variety of topologies to form a running Sitecore solution catering to specific business needs or requirements.

The logical roles can be grouped and described from different perspectives depending on the objective:

1. **By product** - where roles are grouped by the product which they are licensed and installed with and in which they are primarily used.
2. **By type** - where roles are grouped by their usage or technology. For example, do they run business logic or do they store data.
3. **By combination** - for scalability or simplicity reasons, some logical roles can be combined to form single running entities in a topology. This is typically application roles sharing codebases, but can also be storage roles.

This is a very wider topic, you have to go through the below links to get dipper understanding of it.

1. `Default topologies` - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/default-topologies.html
2. `Architecture Overview` - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/architecture-overview.html
3. `Roles overview` - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/roles-overview.html
4. `Data flows and processes` - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/data-flows-and-processes.html

Regarding Communication between XP services, There is a section called `XP service roles`, Which will provide plenty of details about it each service in this link (https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/roles-overview.html)

Hope it helps!